# Can I use Google maps for a non web-based project?

Tags: google-maps, screenshot, offlineapps

I would like to know if I can use the maps of Google Maps in a **non** web-based application. I would use "screenshots" only, or something like that.

I'm trying to understand [Terms of services](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en&csw=1) but sounds a little bit complicated to me... :(

Can you help me?

Thank u in advance :)

Comment: There is also an Android and iOS API, as well. Not sure what the terms of service has to do with the question, though.

Comment: Yes you can by using Android API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean entirely without a data connection then no. Speaking about the web API licence agreement then all maps must be public facing and accessible by all to meet the conditions. [See section 9.1](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en&csw=1). The application must not be behind a firewall etc.

You can however use them offline with the Android or IOS API's or simply print a map for personal use if that's what you're looking for?

Considering you want to use it in a game I would say no, at least not without contacting Google and confirming. I would suggest looking into [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100) as an alternative. The map tiles are open source and thus downloadable.

Comment: By non web-based application I mean a multiplatform videogame :)

Comment: Oh, what a dumb... going to consider OSM :) TY :)